# Cropping an image before sending to the server on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I'm trying to crop an image before sending to the server and I'm having issues.

I'm was trying to do this:

`imageUploadReq.photo = [self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(fileData, 0.07f)]];`

But Xcode is complaining that "Incompatible pointer types passing NSData * to parameter type UIImage". I tried to cast it, but it wouldn't work either.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)uploadPhoto {

   NSData *fileData;

   if (self.image != nil) {
       UIImage *newImage = [self resizeImage:self.image toWidth:320.0f andHeight:480.0f];
       fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.07f);
   }

    WUTModelImageUploadReq *imageUploadReq = [[WUTModelImageUploadReq alloc]init];

    // I'm trying to set the first parameter of UIImageJPEGRepresentation to fileData 
    imageUploadReq.photo = [self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.viewControllerPost.imageForPost, 0.07f)]];
    imageUploadReq.extension = @"jpg";


    void (^wsSuccessHandler)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary* responseObject) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"Pull Feed responseObject %@",responseObject);

    NSError *error;
    WUTModelPostImageResponse *wsResponse = [[WUTModelPostImageResponse alloc]initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)responseObject error:&error];

    if (error) {
        errorMessage = @"Failure to upload image.";
        [self postExecuteFail];
    }else{
        if (wsResponse.success) {
            WUTModelImage *imageTemp = [wsResponse.data firstObject];
            [postItem setObject:imageTemp.photo forKey:@"photo"];
            [self uploadPostFeed];

        }else{
            errorMessage = @"Failure to upload image.";
            [self postExecuteFail];
        }
     }
  };

    void (^wsErrorHandler)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    if ([error.localizedDescription rangeOfString:@"401"].location != NSNotFound)
        errorMessage = @"It seems that your login session get expire, Please relogin after logged out.";
    else
        errorMessage = @"Failure to upload image.";
    [self postExecuteFail];
  };

  AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [WUTCommonWebServices WebServicePostCallWithAccessTokenForEndPoint:WS_UploadImage WithJson:imageUploadReq ForSuccess:wsSuccessHandler ForFailure:wsErrorHandler];
  [op start];

}
```

Comment: What's `WUTModelImageUploadReq`, especially it's property `photo`? What's `encodeToBase64String:`?

Comment: where are you cropping the image here?

Comment: I'm cropping it here `UIImage *newImage = [self resizeImage:self.image toWidth:320.0f andHeight:480.0f];`

Comment: @Larme Photo is a the property that hold the image.

Comment: It's still unclear. photo is a UIImage? a NSString? What's the definition of `encodeToBase64String:`?

Comment: @Larme  photo has a property and is a NSString. This is the helper method for encodeToBase64String: `- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
    return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}`

Comment: In the line with issue replace fileData with newImage.

Comment: @Larme Sorry, but Xcode throws an error. Error is:  Use of undeclared identifier 'newImage'

Comment: imageUploadReq.photo = [self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithData:fileData]];

Comment: @Larme It didn't work. The photo didn't upload to the server in the app.

Comment: What shows NSLog(@"Error: %@", error") if that fails?

Comment: @Larme I tried putting in the `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);` but Xcode didn't spit anything out in the logs when it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need this:

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;    }
```

You just need to pass original image and your desired size and it will return your expected image.

Call the method like:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; // here originalImage is image taken from camera or you can use whatever you want

UIImage * image = [GlobalFunction imageWithImage:originalImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)]; // GlobalFunction is class where I have defined this method and it returns UIImage of size (200, 200)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this a category or a helper method?

Comment: Its a helper method. Just pass your original image and expected size and it will return cropped image with your expected size. If this is what you needed, then accept the answer.

Comment: How do I pass an image using this helper method?  Like this? https://gist.github.com/lumierephoto/04664b705b80b63d8cb4